# sql query UPDATE t1 FROM t1 JOIN (SELECT)

Tags: sql, join, select

I have

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cards t1
```

```
    t1
SET
    t1.driver = t2.mv,
    t1.number = t2.pt
FROM 
    cards t1
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT meta_value mv, post_title pt
        FROM wpwx_posts 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wpwx_postmeta AS PM
        ON post_id = ID
        AND meta_key = 'cardholder'
        WHERE post_type='bilet') t2
    ON t1.number = t2.pt
```

The code in () is correct and can be used

```
FROM cards AS t1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT PM.meta_value AS mv, P.post_title AS pt
        FROM wpwx_posts AS P 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wpwx_postmeta AS PM
        ON PM.post_id = ID
        AND PM.meta_key = 'cardholder'
        WHERE P.post_type='bilet') AS t2
    ON t1.number = t2.pt
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking a better questions.

Comment: I can't get your question about which query doesn't work? can you add some description?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you're trying to update the table, and using `FROM` after `SET` would be invalid syntax. Posting the whole query would be helpful.

Comment: This answer is more suited as a comment...just sayin.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani I don't have the permission to comment yet :) That's why I had to write it as an answer. I can only reply.

Comment: I understand fully. But comments as answers are frowned on at SO. Its just part of paying your dues.